# how to make a grid of images with binding in the xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

how to make a grid of images with binding in the xamarin forms?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinRocket.ViewModel;assembly=XamarinRocket"
             x:DataType="local:XamarinRocket2ViewModel" 
             x:Class="XamarinRocket.Views.XamarinRocket2Page">
    
        <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="ColumnSpacing" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="RowSpacing" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>


    <!--    DICA 2    -->
    
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <Grid>
        
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       
            <local:PinchToZoomContainer>
            <local:PinchToZoomContainer.Content>
                  
                   
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">

                                <Image Aspect="AspectFill"
                         HeightRequest ="75" WidthRequest="75"
                         Source="{Binding ImageName}" />


                            </StackLayout>
                       

                    
                </local:PinchToZoomContainer.Content>
  </local:PinchToZoomContainer>
            <Image Grid.RowSpan="1" Source="{Binding}" x:Name="grdImage" IsVisible="false"/>

        </Grid>
        </ContentPage.Content>
   
    
  </ContentPage>
```

how to make a grid of images with binding in the xamarin forms?
I would like to make a custom xamarin forms code with binding and imagesview, but I don't know how to define the columns?

Comment: please clarify what you mean.  Do you want to bind the grid to a list and have it auto-generate rows and columns?   Or do you have a fixed set of cells that you want to bind to a static set of images?

Comment: i get using it https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout, but I am not able to initialize the view, I will redo the project

Comment: Apparently, you are not using `CollectionView` with custom layout in your provided code snippet.You could define a grid column with `Grid.ColumnDefinitions`.